# extract text from cells after string pattern in Excel

Tags: regex, excel, database

I have a spreadsheet an in each cell there's a chunk of data but I am only interested in extracting a particular piece of information, after including the FIRST date up until the word "Base" example:

FROM ->

```
[extra data] 10APR18 [in between text] 11JUL18 [in between text] etc. Base [extra data]
```

TO ->

```
10APR18 [in between text] 11JUL18 [in between text] etc.
```

I'm not too familiar with the needed syntax, but I'd guess it would something all the lines of extracting everything after:"(number)(number)(letter)(letter)(letter)(number)(number)" up to "Base"

If anyone could shed some light on a solution or point me in the right direction, I'd be incredibly grateful. Thanks!

Comment: You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Then give a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/im-new-to-stack-overflow-what-are-some-things-i-should-do-and-what-things-wil).

Comment: Are those Square brackets present in the text, or they they only as an example?

Comment: As an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

`(\d{2}[A-Za-z]{3}\d{2}.*)Base`

Example: https://regex101.com/r/AO1qmW/1

Explanation:

- `(\d{2}[A-Za-z]{3}\d{2}.*)` - Capture from the date up until `Base`

  - `\d{2}` - Match two digits
  - `[A-Za-z]{3}` - Match three letters, upper or lower case
  - `\d{2}` - Match two more digits
  - `.*`  - Match anything following the date (up until `Base`)
- `Base` - Matches `Base`, but doesn't capture

You can also use a positive lookahead to not have to worry about capturing/non-capturing groups, since you'd only match what you want: `\d{2}[A-z]{3}\d{2}.*(?=Base)`

Only difference is removal of group parenthesis and replacing `Base` with `(?=Base)`, which matches if the previous expression is followed by `Base`.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/SPzslJ/1

Comment: I will give this a shot and get back to you. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest either `[A-Za-z]{3}` or just `[A-Z]{3}` and set the case insensitive flag.  Reason being that there are 1/2 dozen or so characters in `[A-z]` that are not letters.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly -- thank you! The explanation for how you formed the expression was incredibly helpful too. Many thanks.